# Create associated object in before_validation callback fails in Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have a self-referential association Pages -> Pages (think of linking). In the before_validation hook associated objects should be created. It worked in Rails 4.0 and now it gives an `StackLevel Too Deep`

```
class Page
    has_many :linked_pages, -> { uniq }, through: :page_links
    before_validation :parse_links
end
```

Within the `parse_links` callback:

```
page = # results from parsing
self.pages.build(linked_pages_id: page.id).save
```

I guess that pages.create now fires the before_validation callback on the parent content. How can I help here?

Is there maybe an option to `create` the associated objet without validating the parent?

Comment: `pages` method is an association right ? To which model it is?

Comment: @ArupRakshit to itself, I updated the question a little

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the option `validate: false`. Like

```
self.pages.
    build(linked_pages_id: page.id).
    save(validate: false)
```